# How to empty cache for an angular4 app while logout

Tags: angular, google-chrome, caching, ionic3

I have a web & mobile app using angluar4 & ionic 3. I have diff access level for userids.
Menu items will be different for each user privilege 
But currently if I re-login I could see previous user items still exist.
Then I have to do empty cache/hard reload to reset the app 
Is there any best option clear the app cache completely while log out. 
I use chrome browser for app usage

Answer (score 0):

You can use a cordova plugin like https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-cache-clear to clear the cache.